# "equal of" vs "equal to"

Tags: phrase-usage, word-difference

Would you tell me what is the difference between "being equal to someone/something" and "being equal of someone/something"?

The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=equal%20of%2C%20equal%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cequal%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cequal%20to%3B%2Cc0) suggests that "equal to" is far more common than "equal of", but I know "[be equal of someone/something](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-the-equal-of-somebody-something)" is a legitimate expression. So, I conclude there should be specific case in which it's preferred over "equal to".

Is there a very specific or narrowed usage for "be equal of"?
I mean, when do you prefer "equal of" over "equal to"? Does "of" allow for specific sentence constructions that "to" can't?

For example, let's use a Longman's sentence:

- "It would be an extensive and sometimes brutal business, but the Society was the equal of the challenge."

What would happen if I change it to

- It would be an extensive and sometimes brutal business, but the Society was equal **to** the challenge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an athlete, say, is being compared to another, or two rivals, it would be apt to use **the equal of** (the noun form) as two entities (humans here) are being compared:

> Jones is Smith's equal.
>
> Jones is the equal of Smith.
>
> Was Professor Moriarty the equal of Holmes?

When the word is used adjectivally, with **equal to**, we'd normally expect a modifier such as **in speed** in the example below:

> Jones is equal to Smith in speed.

That isn't to say that **the equal of Smith in speed** would be wrong, but that the bald statement **Jones is equal to Smith** isn't quite right without some modifier.  The bald statement makes them out to be quantities.